# realization map for K-theory of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, vector-bundles

Let $\overset{\sim}{K}(X)$ and $\overset{\sim}{KO}$ denote the reduced stable isomorphic classes of complex and real bundles over X and $\rho$ be the realization map. We know that $\overset{\sim}{K}(\mathbb{S}^2)\to\overset{\sim}{KO}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is a map $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_2$ and is non-zero since the realization of the Hopf bundle will be non-zero. Is $\overset{\sim}{K}(\mathbb{S}^{8t+2})\to\overset{\sim}{KO}(\mathbb{S}^{8t+2})$ (which is also $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_2$) non-zero map for any $t\geq 0$? If it's true, please give a reference.

Comment: The forgetful map $KU\rightarrow KO$ is compatible with the Bott periodicities, which answers your question.  As to reference, I don't know a good one, but one can deduce the above using what you can find in sections 1.2 and 1.4 of Neil Strickland's thesis https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/research/thesis.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If this map $\pi_{8t+1}U\to \pi_{8t+1}O$ were trivial then $\pi_{8t+1}(O/U)$ would have an element of order $2$. But $O/U$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega O$, and $\pi_{8t+2}O$ is trivial.

I do not know a reference offhand.